# Redirect to 404 when error occurred in YII2

Tags: yii2

I want to redirect to 404 custom page if any error occurred instead of custom error page with my code. I want to do this as I do not want to show my error stack trace to user. How to achieve this goal? So how can we turn off errors or notifications in YII2.

Answer (score 1, accepted):

You need to set following in `web/index.php` or for advanced app browse to `frontend/web/index.php`

```
defined('YII_DEBUG') or define('YII_DEBUG', false);
```

**OR**

You can throw custom error with status code. For Example,

```
throw new \yii\web\NotFoundHttpException(status code);
```

Comment: thank you but ,may I know what is meant by defined('YII_DEBUG') here?

Comment: It is an constant defines how much call stack information (file name and line number) should be logged.

Comment: ok thanks and when I we do debug false it will redirects to white screen but if I want a 404 redirect for any error then what should I do for that?

Comment: You can make custom error page and you can find it in `view/site/error.php` or in advanced `frontend/view/site/error.php`

Comment: sorry but one more confusion why there is 'or' statement and why we cant simply do define('YII_DEBUG', false);

Comment: one more thing to clear is if we completely change the errorr.php then there is no need to debug false and is it a better approach to edit error.php instead of debug false?

Comment: first `defined('YII_DEBUG')` is constant or second `define('YII_DEBUG', false)` is use for development mode and disable for production mode.

Comment: `defined('YII_DEBUG')` is debugging mode. You have to set it  false show any custom error or it will display error with code and line numbers. After setting it  false you can use custom error page like `error.php`.